# Showing 3 is an irreducible element of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$

Tags: ring-theory, proof-verification, ideals

What I tried:

$$(3)=\{3r|r\in \mathbb Z\}\space\mbox{is a maximal ideal of}\space\mathbb Z\implies(3)=\{3(a+b\sqrt{2})|a,b\in\mathbb Z\}\space\mbox{is a maximal ideal of }\mathbb Z[\sqrt{2}]\hspace{10mm}(*)$$

Since $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$ is an integral domain and $3\in\mathbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$ is an non-zero and non-invertible (shown on a previous exercise) element this implies $3$ is prime and hence is irreducible.

My argument rests on $(*)$ being true and I tried to prove it as follows:

Suppose there exists an ideal $J$ in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$ such that $(3)\subset J\subset \mathbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$. Then the elements in $J$ are of the form $a+b\sqrt{2}$ where $a,b\in\mathbb Z$. Since $(3)$ is a subset of $J$, it must contain all elements of $\{3m|m\in\mathbb Z\}$ and $\{3n\sqrt{2}|n\in\mathbb Z\}$. However, as $(3)$ is maximal in $\mathbb Z$ this implies there is no other ideal, other than the trivial ideal, which contains $(3)$. This forces the $a$ part and $b$ part of elements in $J$ to be divisible by $3\implies a+b\sqrt{2}=3(\alpha+\beta\sqrt{2})\in(3)$ of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$. We now have $p\in J\implies p\in (3)$, which contradicts our original assumption. Therefore $(3)$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$.

$(*)$ seems to be intuitively true but I wasn't sure. Would appreciate it if someone could check if my line of reasoning is correct, or if correct how I could make the argument clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line "This forces the $a$ part and $b$ part of elements in $J$ to be divisible by $3$..." is not correct. For example, up to this point the same argument would apply to $7$ in place of $3$, but $7=(3+\sqrt{2})(3-\sqrt{2})$ shows that $(7)$ is not maximal.

Answer (score 3):

As shown in the answer by Paul Garrett, the reasoning is not correct. The idea, however, of using the fact that $(3)$ is a maximal ideal of ${\mathbb Z}$ to prove that $(3)$ is a maximal (or just prime) ideal of ${\mathbb Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is sound.

You could do: ${\mathbb Z}[\sqrt{2}]/(3) \cong {\mathbb Z}[x]/(x^2-2,3) \cong {\mathbb F}_3[x]/(x^2 - 2)$. Then argue that this last ring is a domain (even a field) and hence the original ideal $(3)$ of ${\mathbb Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ a prime ideal.

(Note, by the way, that the (*) you find intuitively true is not that trivial. It hinges on the fact that $2$ is not a square in ${\mathbb F}_3$.)

Comment: Thanks for the alternate line of reasoning. Yeah, proving (*) is becoming a lot more work than i initially thought.

Comment: It is quite often that going to a quotient ring simplifies computation. Even if you explicitly try to show that $3$ doesn't factor as $(a + b \sqrt{3})(c + d \sqrt{3})$, at some point you're somehow going to look modulo $3$ anyway.

Comment: Yep, the given answer for the assignment looked for solutions to $a^{2}-2b^{2}=3$ mod 3, i was just trying to find alternate/slick methods.